# Bring hidden Gnome 3 notifications back

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I was working with Gnome 3 network settings, and accidentally clicked the "Hide" button on a VPN disconnect notification. Unfortunately, this means whenever my VPN gets disconnected, it doesn't say anything.

Is there any way to get this back?

I'm thinking deleting my configuration folder should work, but presumably there's an easier way (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution just now:

- Install `gconf-editor` if necessary
- Open `gconf-editor` ("ConfigurationEditor" in the menu)
- Open `/apps/nm-applet` in the left panel
- In the right panel, uncheck `disable-vpn-notifications` (or other notifications)

Presumably other Gnome 3 notifications are similar.

Hopefully someone else knows of a more user-friendly way of doing this.